# Mount breaker subpanel on edge of cinder block wall?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, subpanel

Can I place a 13" x 11" subpanel (mounted onto a 12" wide shelf board) on the edge of a cinder block wall that divides two rooms?  It's in a large pass through between the two rooms, so there would be easily 3 feet in front of the panel and a 30" wide clearance. It's just that the panel board will extend beyond the wall surface a few inches on either side.

Comment: 13x11, you're talking 6 space panel (maybe 8-space in CH or QO), and I disrecommend that because it will fill up rather quickly.  Breaker spaces are cheap, get plenty.  Also, cost-wise, copper gets prohibitive above 30A, and you're better off going 2-2-2-4 aluminum, which is fine in that large size.  Now you have 90A to play with!

Comment: I think we spoke before.  My concern was the location--the end edge of a wall.  I've never read about anyone doing this or asking this question.  The box is an Eaton BR 8/16 and I plan to use tandem breakers.  I'll have plenty of room and there's still plenty of room in the main panel.  It's just that I wanted to take advantage of an unused 50A cable so as to shorten the run of many of the circuits,  And it will never exceed 50A since most of the circuits are not used simultaneously.